# Java IllegalArgumentException: MONTH

Tags: java, hibernate

When I am trying to save an entity into the DB I get the following error and I don't where the mistake could be. I am using only LocalDate. I have an example of entity below.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MONTH
at java.base/java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2645) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:3433) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1815) ~[na:na]
at com.mysql.cj.result.SqlTimestampValueFactory.localCreateFromDatetime(SqlTimestampValueFactory.java:191) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
at com.mysql.cj.result.SqlTimestampValueFactory.localCreateFromDatetime(SqlTimestampValueFactory.java:51) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
at com.mysql.cj.result.AbstractDateTimeValueFactory.createFromDatetime(AbstractDateTimeValueFactory.java:104) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MysqlTextValueDecoder.decodeDatetime(MysqlTextValueDecoder.java:90) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.decodeAndCreateReturnValue(AbstractResultsetRow.java:86) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.getValueFromBytes(AbstractResultsetRow.java:243) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.ByteArrayRow.getValue(ByteArrayRow.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getTimestamp(ResultSetImpl.java:939) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getTimestamp(ResultSetImpl.java:977) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getTimestamp(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.TimestampTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(TimestampTypeDescriptor.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3131) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1863) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1791) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1764) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1616) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:740) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1039) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:990) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:959) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:319) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2415) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4437) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4427) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:576) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:544) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:332) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
```

I am not sure what else to attach as code, but the booking entity looks like this:

```html
@Entity
@Table(name = "bookings")
public class BookingEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Instant bookingTime;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDate checkIn;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDate checkOut;
```

Comment: You need a converter to turn a `LocalDate` into an `SQLDate` https://thorben-janssen.com/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/

Comment: which version of hibernate are you using? version 5.3 should support LocalDate conversion out of the box

Comment: @hfontanez thank you for pointing the problem, I didn't know what to look for. I added @Column(columnDefinition = "DATE") and it worked.                                           
Hibernate version is 5.4.32.

Comment: @sjs I suggest you post your solution as an answer and selected as such to help others. You can answer your own questions in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem in adding

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "DATE")
```